# what does the union of those 3 events imply

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

> Let there be 3 events:
>
> - A=a dish got broken
> - B= electric product stopped working
> - C= the car got broken
>
> Write the following event, D= at least 2 problem occurred.

$D=(A\cap B)\cup (B\cap C)\cup (A \cap C) $

that mean that $(A\cap B\cap C)\subseteq D$?

Comment: what do you mean by $(A\cap B\cap C)\in D$?

Comment: Sorry fixed, meant subset of D

Comment: Yes, $Q:=A\cap B\cap C\subseteq D$, because $$Q\subseteq A\wedge Q\subseteq B\implies Q\subseteq A\cap B\subseteq D$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *implies* that $(A \cap B \cap C) \subset D$. Among other ways to see this, look at a [Venn Diagram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VennDiagram.html).

But I would ordinarily think that "P means Q" is intended to be same as "P is logically equivalent to Q". If that's what you intended then $D = (A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (A \cap C)$ does not mean $(A \cap B \cap C) \subset D$, they are not logically equivalent, because the set $(A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (A \cap C)$ can contain stuff that the set $A \cap B \cap C$ does not contain. Again, you can see that in the Venn Diagram.

Comment: What do you refer as "P means Q" that is because of the usage of the letter "D="? If I would just ask
$(A\cap B \cap C) \subset (A\cap B)\cup (B\cap C)\cup (A \cap C)$ that would not be "P means Q"?

Comment: Yes, in my abbreviation "P means Q" the intent was that "P" and "Q" stand for two complete mathematical sentences: "P" stands for the sentence "$D = (A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (C \cap A)$" and "Q" stands for "$(A \cap B \cap C) \subset D$". I think this is one of those places where our ordinary logical language is a little too imprecise for mathematical usage. I guess I try generally to avoid that 5 letter word "means" in precise contexts. In this case P implies Q but P is not logically equivalent to Q. @gbox

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. If an element is in $(A\cap B\cap C)$, then evidently it is in all three sets $(A\cap B), (B\cap C),(A \cap C)$ and hence is in their union and, therefore, in $D$.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting $D$, you obtain $(A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (A \cap C)$ = $B \cap (A \cup C) \cup (A \cap C)$ = $B \cap (A \cup C)$. Finally, $A \cap B \cap C= B \cap (A \cap C) \subset B \cap (A \cup C)$ because of set monotony.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a subset as all the elements are contained in D